# How to check if individual character in a string exists in another string for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Is there any library that allows me to check If all the individual characters in one string exists in another string. When i try to use `in` what happens is the character has to be a substring. It only works for `1234` and `123`. However i want something that checks individual characters. I want a library that gives me the output: `string 2 is in string 1` for the following code.

```
string1 = '1234'
string2 = '24'

if string2 in string1:
    print('string2 is in string1')
else:
    print('string2 is not in string1')
```

Comment: Asking for library/software recommendations is explicitly off-topic, see [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all()` with a generator. This returns a true only if all conditions are a true else false:

```
string1 = '1234'
string2 = '24'

if all(x in string1 for x in string2):
    print('string2 is in string1')
else:
    print('string2 is not in string1')
```

Or, you can use set's `issubset`:

```
set(string2).issubset(string1)
```

Comment: Alternatively... `if set(string2).issubset(string1)`... (which although has the overhead of building a set - that shouldn't be too bad) and it potentially avoids unnecessary look ups...

Comment: @JonClements, I believe for large strings set would be faster (that iteration would then match up with overhead of building set)?

Comment: running timeit's, then they're pretty much equal for both `all` and `set`... setting the strings to be `* 1000` works out about 40% faster for set.

Comment: @JonClements, worth adding to answer.